# How can a single view access multiple models in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i am developing an application in MVC3.
Basically it is an Question Forum where on Question page user will see all questions as link and a post comment box at the end.and when he clicks on question link he is moved to the answers page.now the answer page is using another model class and their i am not able to acess my answer class data

what i found was every Controller has a view and a model
but i want my view to access multiple models and i dont knw how to go about it..

I tried this:

```
 public class MainClass
{
    public Question_Page question{ get; set; }
    public Answer_Page answer { get; set; }
} 
  public class Question_Page
{
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual string Question_name { get; set; }
   public virtual DateTime Created_Date { get; set; }
   public virtual DateTime Modified_Date { get; set; }
   public virtual int Created_By { get; set; }
   public virtual int Modified_By { get; set; }
   public virtual char Deleted { get; set; }
   public Question_Page()
   {
        this.Deleted='F';
   }
}

 public class Answer_Page
  {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Answer { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Created_Date { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Modified_Date { get; set; }
    public virtual int Created_By { get; set; }
    public virtual int Modified_By { get; set; }
    public virtual char Deleted { get; set; }
    public virtual Question_Page Question { get; set; }
     public Answer_Page()
    {
        this.Deleted='F';
    }
}
```

Now inside the view of Questions List where i display a list of questions:

```
@model IEnumerable<Core.Model.MainPage>
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }
 <style type="text/css">
 ul
 {
   list-style-type: none;
 }
 </style>
 <h2>All Questions</h2>
 <hr />

 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Question",FormMethod.Post))
 {
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  <ul>
   @foreach (var item in Model) 
  {

     <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.Question_name, "answer", new { Qry = item.Id })</li>
   }
   </ul>

  <label for="PostyourQuestion:">Post your Question:</label><br /><br />
  @Html.TextArea("textID")    
  <br />
  <input type="submit"/>
  }
```

after doing this much i am gettin errorin line:
      @foreach (var item in Model)

This is my controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new StudentService().GetAllStudents());
    }
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Question_Page question,string textID)
    {         
        question.Question_name = textID;
        question.Created_Date = DateTime.Now;
        question.Modified_Date = DateTime.Now;
        question.Created_By = 101;
        question.Modified_By = 101; 
        new StudentService().SaveOrUpdateStudent(question);
        return View(new StudentService().GetAllStudents());
    }
```

StudentService is a class where i hv defined the methods GetAllStudents(),SaveOrUpdateStudent()

Please help me

Comment: It really depends on how u contruct ur model on the controller before you return the view. Would be helpful to help you, if u can post ur controllers.

Comment: @tsegay i have updated my question please have a look at it

Comment: Btw you want a specific ViewModel, unrelated to the Persistence Model which you're currently using as the view model. Separate them and everything will be much clear and easier

Comment: @user1274646 Sorry for my late response. You still need to clean up ur Controller class, I dont see the return type from your StudentService Class. see my Answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is rather simple I think?

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
```

should be

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Question_Page)
```

Your model is `MainPage`?

can you post that model here as well?

Comment: i tried this  but still m gettin an error:
MainPage does not contain the definition for Question_Page

Answer (score 0):

assume that GetAllStudents() return `IEnumerable<Student>`
in your controller

```
return View(new StudentService().GetAllStudents());
```

the actual **Model** send to View is `IEnumerable<Student>`

if you need `IEnumerable<Core.Model.MainPage>` as Model just return proper objects from your controller

```
IEnumerable<Core.Model.MainPage> model = //... define function that return Enumerable MainPage
return View(model);
```

Answer (score 0):

If You want to use the same model on different views

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //I am assuming, You are returning IEnumerable<MainClass>
        List<MainClass> mainClass=new StudentService().GetAllStudents();
        if(mainClass==null)
            mainClass=new List<MainClass>(); //Incase you are not checking null value return
        return View(mainClass); //return a none null IEnumerable<MainClass> object
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Question_Page question,string textID)
    {         
        question.Question_name = textID;
        question.Created_Date = DateTime.Now;
        question.Modified_Date = DateTime.Now;
        question.Created_By = 101;
        question.Modified_By = 101; 
        new StudentService().SaveOrUpdateStudent(question);
        return View(new StudentService().GetAllStudents());
    }
```

Once your first controller method works, you will need to work on binding your model, for the second post method to work.

Answer (score 0):

try viewModel. A model that have references to your desired model. so if a view is bound to your view model, then all the models referenced in the ViewModel will also get bonded.